# How to replace a foreignkey with another using a migration

Tags: django, django-models, django-migrations

I'd like to replace an existing `ForeignKey` pointing at my User model with one pointing at a profile model.

The change in the model is:

```
created_by=models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODULE)
```

To:

```
created_by=models.ForeignKey(settings.PROFILE_MODEL)
```

The auto-generated migration looks like (with constants subbed in):

```
migrations.AlterField(
        model_name=MODEL,
        name='created_by',
        field=models.ForeignKey(to=settings.PROFILE_MODEL),
        preserve_default=True,
    ),
```

I also have `ManyToManyFields` to deal with as well. What I have in my head is I'd like a function to run on each MODEL object to resolve the user object to the profile object. How would I go about doing this?

The relationship between user and profile is (and vice versa):

```
User.profile = Profile
```

**Edit:** Forgot to mention, if the auto-generated migration is run you get the following error:

```
ValueError: Lookup failed for model referenced by field 
APP1.MODEL.created_by: APP2.PROFILE_MODEL
```

Comment: The answer is completely rewritten. (I expect you mean AUTH_USER_MODEL instead of AUTH_USER_MODULE.)

Comment: managed to find the root of the `ValueError`, it seems makemigrations was not adding the app of the new FK to (ie APP2 in above) to the migration's dependencies. Unsure but this feels like a bug.

Comment: Is that APP2 in INSTALLED_APPS? That "Lookup failed for model referenced by field" in Django 1.7 source is usually caused by a missing app in INSTALLED_APPS or by circular dependency of migrations. If your code seems OK, write a minimal example of the bug. I can try to confirm it and participate on reporting issue. A clear end is welcome.

Comment: App is in INSTALLED_APPS. I'll make a new project to see if I can reproduce this in a clean environment and put it on github.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand now you want to migrate only our app without expecting anything to be changed to the global auth User model. Then it's easy. Migrations work nice with symbolic settings names.

I tried it with Django 1.7. It is possible to switch between settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL and settings.PROFILE_MODEL back and forth **without any problem**. A migration can be created and applied after every change. The tested model had also a ManyToManyField and mutual relationships between User and Profile.

I see you have APP1 and APP2. Maybe you make migrations for both and they are circular dependent so that a part of other application migration should be applied before the current one migration can be completely applied and vice versa. It can be simplified by spliting a change to more smaller and making automatic migrations after every change so that they are less dependent. A `OneToOneField` is better than two mutual foreign keys and its reverse relation is even so useful. A foreign key can be changed temporarily to `IntegerField(null=True)` in the worst case in order to simplify data migration. It is really viable more or less nice.

The question looked nice initially, but the problem should be better specified to be reproducible.

**Edited by removing the original text after reading information in comments:**

Comment: 1) I don't think it is, the actual error returned is `ValueError: Lookup failed for model referenced by field xsd_training.PerformedLesson.trainee: xsd_members.MemberProfile` I just subbed out my apps names for generic ones to make the question simpler. I don't see how doing this will help, rather it will pass absolute names to the migration files which is not wanted.

Comment: 2) That looks like my question, not sure what you're getting at though

Comment: I added more info to the answer.

Comment: I've read the warnings, but I'm pretty sure this is doable. From inspecting the database the foreign key relationships the docs are referring to are simply the names of the FK columns (user_id), I've addressed this by calling my custom user User (ie `myapp.User`).

Comment: The steps, as I see them, would be: - create new user table, - migrate data from old user to new user, - change `AUTH_USER_MODEL` and FK relationships, cross fingers and hope all works. My issue is fitting this in django's migration system, which I'd like to do to keep deployment relatively painless.

Comment: apologies, the problem comes from quite a convoluted application, I've done my best to simplify it so that it can be reproduced, can't remember myself why I was doing with the APP1 and APP2 nonsense!